# Workbook_SheetChange() being called while waiting for data load from DB

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have a C# VSTO application. When the application starts, Excel sheets are populated with data from SQL server. Once the data is completely loaded, I want to initialize the `Workbook_SheetChange`().

Error - Currently, this event handler object is created when the Excel workbook loads and while the data is being loaded in the sheets, the event is triggered on loop (which is not right). I want to be able to either:
a. Identify the cell values are being changed by the user manually OR
b. Create the Event handler only when the data is done being loaded in the sheets from db.

This is how it's implemented right now

```cs
//create event handler
this.Application.SheetChange += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.AppEvents_SheetChangeEventHandler(ActiveWorkbook_SheetChange);

//method triggered
private void ActiveWorkbook_SheetChange(object Sh, Range Target)
{
    if (Target.Value2 != null)
    {
        string changedRange = Target.get_Address(XlReferenceStyle.xlA1);

        if (changedRange.Contains("$AH$"))
        {
            UiSheet.PriceLadders(changedRange);
        }

        if (changedRange.Contains("$AI$"))
        {
            UiSheet.PriceLadders(changedRange);
        }

        if (changedRange.Contains("$AM$"))
        {
            UiSheet.PriceLadders(changedRange);
        }

        if (changedRange.Contains("$AN$"))
        {
            UiSheet.PriceLadders(changedRange);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Target.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 215, 175);
    }
}
```

Comment: `the event is triggered on loop (which is not right)` - no, this is exactly right. `Workbook_SheetChange` (and `Worksheet_Change`) are triggered after every act of changing a sheet. If you don't like that, either [disable the events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.enableevents) or do not subscribe to them until you've made all changes.

Comment: "Excel sheets are populated with data from SQL server" - is that code you control or at least call? If so, then the solutions of GSerg will work a charm. If not, you'll need to provide more detail on how exactly the SQL is loaded.